# Basic chainset compatibility question

Tags: mountain-bike, parts, chainring, compatibility

I need to replace my chainset (42x34x22). Would a 42x32x22 be a compatible replacement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that all other things, e.g. type/diameter of the axle, are the same, the difference of two teeth on the middle chainring do not present a problem.

Comment: You could just change the chain-rings provided the crank is still OK and that the rings are bolted on rather than riveted.